# popUpTo seems not to work in Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

so I'm using the  android navigation component and I have a problem (2.2.0-rc04 version).

I have a `welcomeFragment`(wF). From `wF` I want to navigate to `loginSellerFragment`(lSF) which is in a different navigation graph. I also don't want to remove `wF` from backstack ( popUpTo, popUpToInclusive) when navigating to `lSF` because a user might wanna go back to it.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/welcomeFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_welcomeFragment_to_nav_onboarding_seller"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:destination="@id/nav_onboarding_seller" />
</fragment>
```

After navigating to lSF the backstack looks like this : **wF lSF**

We're on `lSF` now, after login we want to go to `feedFragment`(fF) which again is in a separate graph, but this time we want to clear all the backstack, because if a user is logged in and presses back he wants the app to exit, not to take him back to `wF` or `lSF`, so I used `popUpTo="@id/loginSellerFragment popUpToInclusive='true"` in the action from `lSF` to `fF`.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginSellerFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_login_to_seller"
        app:destination="@+id/seller" . //this is the graph that has as firstDestination, feedFragment
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/loginSellerFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

So in the backstack in this moment should be only **fF** because we removed everything up to `lSF`(`lSF` included)

**The problem**

When I'm on `fF` and press back, the app doesn't close, instead it takes me to `wF` ( `wF` should have been popped off the backstack already)

**What I've tried**

I've tried instead of `popUpTo="@id/loginSellerFragment popUpToInclusive='true"` to use `popUpTo="@id/welcomeFragment popUpToInclusive='true"` and it worked fine, but I'm pretty sure that this is not how it should be done. What am I missing here guys? Am I building the backstack wrong?

Also I've tried adding `popUpTo="@id/welcomeFragment popUpToInclusive='true"` after navigating from `wF` to `lSF` , but this will break my user experience, because I don't want the app to exit when I'm still in the login process.

Please note that all of this fragments are in separate graphs. 
To navigate I use `FragmentDirections` e.g : `findNavController.navigate(WelcomeFramgentDirections.actionXtoY())`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not easy to grasp how Navigation Component manipulates backstack when you are using `popUpTo` option.

The solution you mentioned in your question is correct:
You indeed should use `popUpTo="@id/welcomeFragment" popUpToInclusive="true"` instead of `popUpTo="@id/loginSellerFragment" popUpToInclusive="true"`.

I will try to explain why.

- When you launch your application, your backstack will be empty and `welcomeFragment` will be displayed.
- When you navigate from `welcomeFragment` to `loginSellerFragment`, you will have `welcomeFragment` in your backstack.
- Than if you login, you will navigate from `loginSellerFragment` to `feedFragment`, and in backstack you will have `loginSellerFragment` and `welcomeFragment`.

Since you used `popUpTo="@id/welcomeFragment"`, aplication will start to pop (remove) fragments from your backstack until it reaches `welcomeFragment`. The `welcomeFragment` will be also removed since we used `popUpToInclusive="true"`.

Backstack should behave like FILO (First In Last Out) stack, so it will remove fragments in this manner:

First the top fragment will be removed and that is `loginSellerFragment`.

Next, `welcomeFragment` will be the top fragment. Since we need to pop up fragments until we reach `welcomeFragment` this is where we stop, but `welcomeFragment` will be also removed because of `popUpToInclusive="true"` and your backstack will be empty.

If you try to navigate back from `welcomeFragment`, you will exit app because your backstack is empty.

I hope that this helps. You could also read more about stack data structure.

Comment: Actually I started to debug a little bit the nav component and came to the conclusion that "I was wrong saying that I'm wrong" :)). Indeed, Initially I tought that `popUpTo` it will start poping up elements from the root of the graph until it reaches the fragment, but it actually behaves in the opposite way( it starts with the most recent fragment added until it reaches the specified fragment. I still find this counter intuitive, but it's nice that somebody finally explained it.

Comment: I do have a question tho, I logged the `onCreate` and `onDestroy` and it seems that first it destroys `loginSellerFragment` and  then `welcomeFragment`. Here are the logs : `14:56:55.898 WelcomeFragment is destroyed
14:56:55.907 SellerLoginFragment is destroyed` . What's the reason for this?

Comment: If you follow second half of my answer, thats the order in which they are supposed to be destroyed. First, the `loginSellerFragment` and than the `welcomeFragment`. One thing not to be confused about: pop up of fragments is not related to graph, but to a backstack.

Comment: I find this unintuitive as well. I get that they want to use "up to" but then it's a stack, so really "up" is toward the recent, but at the same time, android operates on "up=previous", so there's the contradiction(if i'm not mistaken) and confusion.

Answer (score 11):

For me setting XML code didn't really solve the issue, had to use an extra line of code

```
  findNavController()
                .navigate(R.id.navigationFragment,
                    null,
                    NavOptions.Builder()
                        .setPopUpTo(R.id.splashFragment,
                            true).build()
                )
```

Comment: It is same for me. I had the same problem and your solution saved me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: same here this really help me. thanks

Comment: same for me, xml did not pop up my specified fragment, but in code it worked